# Is there an Infinite dimensional sheaf theory for analysis on manifolds?

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, ap.analysis-of-pdes, smooth-manifolds, sheaf-theory, derived-categories

I apologize if this question is slightly vague but I don't know how to ask it non-vaguely. Moreover, my question is about an ideal situation. If there's a close answer which doesn't satisfy all the conditions it will still worth a lot!

Let $\mathcal{C}$ be the category of smooth (/analytic) manifolds.

The question is about existence of certain definitions which admit certain properties. Here are the definitions I require:

> 1. A grothendieck topology $J$ on $\mathcal{C}$
> 2. A closed symmetric-monoidal stable $\infty$-category $\mathcal{V}$ (or triangulated if you prefer, though descent issues should then be handled carefully).

Here are the properties I'd like them to satisfy:

---

> 1. The cohomology theory of $\mathcal{V}$-valued $J$-sheaves on $\mathcal{C}$ has all six functors.

This means that for every map $f: X \to Y$, we have four functors: $f_!,f^!,f^*,f_*$ on the corresponding categories of sheaves with the familiar adjunctions between them. Moreover there are the functors $\otimes, \mathcal{Hom(-,-)}$.

> 2. There's a natural way to assign to any differential complex of vector bundles $E_\bullet$ on a manifold $X$ its corresponding complex of sheaf of (compactly supported-) sections (smooth/analytic/distributional/sobolev etc...) as an object in $Sh(X,\mathcal{V})$

In other words for every manifold $X$ there exist (well behaved) sheaves of section functors $Diff(X) \overset{\Gamma^{\#}}{\to} Sh(X,\mathcal{V})$ with $\# = \text{smooth, analytic, distributional, continuous, sobolev etc...}$. Where $Diff(X)$ is the $dg$-category of complexes of differential operators between vector bundles and morphism complexes are the complexes of differential operators between shifts.

> 3. Verdier duality $Sh(X,\mathcal{V})$ is compatible with schwartz kernels when they exist.

This means that in "favorable situations" we'd want sections of $\mathbb{D}\mathcal{E} \otimes \mathcal{F}$ to correspond to certain kernels of integral operators living in $\mathcal{D}(X \times X, E^*\otimes Dens_X \otimes F)$ (with some regularity in the $F$ direction).

---

This is not the most complete list one could write, and it's terribly imprecise. I've avoided being too precise because i'm not sure what really one should ask for. What I wrote was only for the purpose of figuring out whether this sort of question has some answers in the literature.

Comment: It might be worth pointing out that the category of (finite-dimensional, paracompact, hausdorff) manifolds is a full subcategory of R-algebras, by taking M to $C^\infty(M)$. Actually, there is a definition of smooth R-algebra, and commutative smooth R-algebras are precisely those coming from manifolds (if I remember correctly). The reason I mention it is that this might help for point 3.

Comment: @YosemiteSam: There is a counterexample to your claim here: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/86426/about-the-category-of-von-neumann-algebras/91445#91445

Comment: @DmitriPavlov you mean I should have said second-countable instead of paracompact?

Comment: @YosemiteSam: Either second-countable, or C^∞-rings instead of R-algebras.

Comment: @DmitriPavlov, thank you for spotting this. I happily retract/edit my original statement (which I incorrectly copied from Nestruev's book). I'm not sure I even care about non-second countable manifolds!

Comment: @DmitriPavlov however, your comment about $C^\infty$ rings raises an interesting point. I'm not familiar with the theory, is there a good theory of coherent sheaves? Because if we just say "module over $C^\infty(M)$ I'm sure that in the non-projective case it won't give us something like what the OP wants.

Comment: @YosemiteSam: If you want a disjoint union of manifolds to be a manifold again, you have to consider non-second-countable manifolds.  A theory of quasi-coherent sheaves over C^∞-rings is developed here: https://arxiv.org/abs/1707.01145

Comment: You may be interested in the Toën-Vaquié formalism built with with Banach spaces (and sheaves thereof) in this nifty paper of Kobi and Oren's. I don't think it gets into the specifics of a 6-functor formalism but you can see some things happening that may be of interest.

LINK: https://arxiv.org/pdf/1312.0338.pdf
NON-ARCHIMEDEAN ANALYTIC GEOMETRY AS RELATIVE ALGEBRAIC GEOMETRY